# "ought" with or without "to"?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, ellipses

We usually say "ought to" not "ought". (Although more often we say "should"). I wonder when I can say "ought" without "to".

Some examples:

- 1: Ought I to tell him?
- 2: Yes, you ought to
- 3: No, you ought not to
- 4: I don't learn as often as I ought to
- 5: ‘Ought I to write to say thank you?’ ‘Yes, I think you ought (to).’ (From Oxford Learner's Dictionary)
- 6: We ought not to have ordered so much food

Can I omit "to" after "ought". Why?

Comment: Yes, you can. One of its properties as an auxiliary is that it occurs in stranding constructions Note that it occurs more readily when old (as in your examples) than when new cf. ?"He's considering selling his car, but I don't think he ought".

Comment: It depends on whether the speaker has internalized _ought_ as a separate item from _oughtta_. It's got no other use and it's rare with an uncomplemented infinitive. Phrases such as _I ought never to have invited him_ feel odd, like formalized variants made up on the spot. It's much more likely to be _should never have_, with no _to_. And a final _ought_ turns into an _oughtta_ most of the time.